# Is it possible for dark energy density be decreasing?

Tags: cosmology, temperature, universe, event-horizon, dark-energy

I have an equation relating **dark energy density** and **temperature**, actually they have a linear relationship, my question is how to choose the temperature? If I choose the temperature of universe, the dark energy density will be decreasing. If thats the case will it contradict any observational results?

Comment: It can be changing but not too much, at least not in the recent history of the universe. See e.g. "dynamical dark energy".